# How to set the authorisation header in angular 4( Not inside the Access-Control-Request-Headers). It should be as a Authorisation: value

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

how to set the authorisation header in angular 4( Not inside the Access-Control-Request-Headers). It should be as a Authorisation: value.

Headers should come as follow as

```
Accept:*/*<br/>
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch<br/>
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8<br/>
**Authorisation:accesstoken**<br/>
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET<br/>
Cache-Control:max-age=0<br/>
Connection:keep-alive<br/>
Host:192.168.1.190:58603<br/>
Origin:http://localhost:4200<br/>
Referer:http://localhost:4200/analytics<br/>
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

But it is coming as follow as:

```
Accept:*/*<br/>
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch<br/>
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8<br/>
**Access-Control-Request-Headers:Authorisation**<br/>
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET<br/>
Cache-Control:max-age=0<br/>
Connection:keep-alive<br/>
Host:192.168.1.190:58603<br/>
Origin:http://localhost:4200<br/>
Referer:http://localhost:4200/analytics<br/>
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```